# How to make Server Sent Events publish to all clients only when there's new data?

Tags: php, push-notification, server-sent-events

How to make Server Sent Events publish to all clients only when there's new data using PHP? 
Most of the resources that I've red are using while loop which is constantly pushing data which is not ideal to me. The basic scenario is when a user send a message, the SSE will publish that data to all clients. The code below is not working because as I've said earlier it constantly sending data.

```
function showData() {
  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Connection: keep-alive');
  header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

  echo ":".str_repeat(" ", 2048)."\n"; //2k padding for IE

  if (connection_aborted()) {
    exit;
  }       

  $chats = Chat::find()->all();

  if (count($chats) > 0):
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($chats as $chat) {
        $messages[] = [
            'id' => $chat->id,
            'message' => $chat->message
        ];

        $lastEventId = $chat->id;
     }

     dataEmitter($lastEventId, $messages);                     
  else:
    dataEmitter(0, ['id' => $lastEventId, 'message' => 'No record found']);
  endif;
}

function dataEmitter($id, $data) {
        echo "id: {$id}" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "data: " . json_encode($data) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL; # This is necessary to get rid headers already sent.
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
    }
```

Comment: is that the entire PHP script that handles the SSE events?

Comment: Yes! But the code emits data after 3 sec. If I'm not mistaken, this is the normal behavior of SSE but I don't like the constantly emitting. I want showData() method to emit only when triggered by maybe a POST method(something like PHP "Pusher") using Curl or PHP Stream. Then after emitting/publishing data, I want showData() function halt or sleep maybe.

Comment: I use SSE frequently but run an infinite loop - with a querystring that supplies configuration parameters such as `sleep`, `event name` etc. So long as you can identify, for specific users, whether or not they have "seen" the messages or not should determine if new messages are emitted. Your code will cause the client to disconnect and reconnect after each message I believe which I'd suggest is not what you want either?! You can't issue a POST request to the SSE script afaik.
Have you thought about/looked at "Push Messages"?